# How to use a var in a folder name

Tags: powershell, variables, directory, rename

I'm creating a `powershell` script to create a folder for projects.

The idea is that I first enter the name of the project, and then use that name in the project folder.
Could anyone please give me a hand on how to rename the "00000 - Project Name" in powershell with the variable entered.

```bsh
$PFname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the new project'
Rename-Item -Path "K:\Projects\00000 - Project Name" -NewName "K:\Projects\00000 - Project Name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you have to do something like this:

```bsh
$PFname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the new project'
$path = "K:\Projects\00000 - Project Name"
$newPath = $path -replace "00000 - Project Name$", $PFname
Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName $newPath
```

The key to complete this is the operator `-replace` to whom you have to pass two values, first the value you are looking for and second the value you want to replace.

After that you have both `$path` that is your old name and `$newPath` which is your result name.

Comment: Please @John check the answer as correct if that resolved your problem, thank you!